# Missing TextUtils from Struts2 Library

Tags: maven, build, struts2, upgrade, textutils

My project was using older versions of Struts2 (2.0.x)
Now we are planning to upgrade Struts2 version which has some improvements and bug fixes.

I updated the pom.xml as per that. However I found out that in my old strtus2-core lib, there's

> > org.apache.struts2.views.util.TextUtil

But in latest version it's not there and I am facing compilation errors.

Any idea why it's missing or how do i get it?

Comment: This class has been deleted from Struts2. Are you using it in you code?

Comment: Yes. That's the reason I am getting erros :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `org.apache.struts2.views.util.TextUtil` was removed from Struts 2 after 2.1.6. You have a few options.

First, as Jaiwo99 indicated, Struts 2 is licensed under the Apache License v2, so you can just take a copy of the source for TextUtil from Struts 2.1.6 and put it in your application. The class has no dependencies on other code, so it should work fine.

Second, you could look at using `StringEscapeUtils` from Apache Commons Lang 3, which is now used by Struts2 for escaping HTML and JavaScript. Specifically, look at `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this one?

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParserUtil
```

Comment: I am not sure. But we are using from Struts2. How do I replace the same. Because it's bit legacy application. Should be handled carefully :)

Comment: @NitinGurram xworks2 is part of struts2! and the class is just moved from `struts2-core` to `xworks`, it is no problem at all

Comment: @NitinGurram please check `xwork-core-x.x.x.jar`, in the package `META-INF`, you can find the license, which is Apache License v2

Comment: TextParseUtil (not TextParserUtil) is not the same class.